# Cannot use external contract addresses as function arguments in Vyper contract interface

Tags: vyper

I'm trying to compile the Uniswap [Exchange contract](https://github.com/Uniswap/contracts-vyper/blob/master/contracts/uniswap_exchange.vy) using the latest `vyper` compiler.

I first updated the ERC20 references to the new `token: ERC20` definition and set up an import `from vyper.interfaces import ERC20`.

The next issue is with the `getExchange()` function in the Factory interface.

```
vyper.exceptions.TypeMismatchException: line 68:15 Typecasting from base type address(ERC20) to address unavailable
```

This occurs on the following line:

```
assert self.factory.getExchange(self.token) == self
```

I tried to solve it by amending the `getExchange` interface to:

```
    def getExchange(token_addr: ERC20) -> address: constant
```

but this produces another error:

```
vyper.exceptions.InvalidTypeException: line 8: Invalid base type: ERC20
    def getExchange(token_addr: ERC20) -> address: constant
```

How to get this to compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was a compiler error and is being addressed.

See here: https://github.com/ethereum/vyper/issues/1375